# Starting up a database instance fails when not connected to my home network

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Every time I'm trying start a database instance and I'm not connected to my home wireless network or wireless is disabled, this is what happens:

```
[mati@Mati-PC ~]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Oct 17 21:07:39 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [keltnfy-ldmInit], [46], [1], [], [], [], [], []
SQL>
```

I have googled the issue, checked /etc/hosts - everything seems OK, including permissions. I'm using Fedora 15.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metalink Note 336447.1 addresses the problem.  It appears to be related to the database server not being able to resolve your system's hostname due to DNS not being available.

Run a caching DNS server on your machine and verify all your DNS-related configuration files and their permissions as described in the note.

Comment: Problem solved. Apparently, I had to change the line in /etc/hosts "127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost" to "<hostname> localhost.localdomain localhost", so it would reflect my hostname (in my case MATI-PC).

Comment: Yup, that'll do it.  It becomes far more important to make sure your hosts file is accurate if you try and use any of Oracle's Fusion Middleware products.